# Get element value from several xml and put it in single xml file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, serialization, xsd

I have several xml file with different elements in it. I have generated a xsd file for each xml file through visual studio and also generated a c# file by typing xsd fileName.xsd
Now i'm trying to get all elements of these various xml file and put it in a single xml file. Any idea how to do it? When i try to serialize each xml file separately i'm not able to fetch the elements value.

Comment: do you want to merge all your XML files

Comment: Ya merge all xml file elements into single xml file

Comment: these files they have common nodes or just you need to combine them into one

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short snippet bellow to merge two XDocuments,

```
    string oldXmlFile = @"Path";
    string newXmlfile = @"Path2";
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(oldXmlFile);
    document.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(newXmlfile).Root.Elements());
    document.Save(oldXmlFile);
```

but then duplicate elements will also populate the merged document, so here comes a handy little method that also checks for duplicate items.

[Merge with duplicate element check (C# Class)](http://blog.halan.se/file.axd?file=2009%2F10%2FHalanTools.zip)